# How do I get the route parameter from another .vue file inside the params folder

Tags: nuxt.js

I have my directory structure kind of like this

```
pages/
└── _id/
   ├── index.vue
   └── edit.vue
```

now I want to access the route of my folder in edit.vue but it says `route is not defined` or `$route is not defined`. In my `created()` I use `route.params.id` or `$route.params.id` to a variable. But I don't think it works. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the `created()` [lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) hook, you have access to the `this` instance. From there you can get the `id` URL param with `this.$route.params.id`.

However, when using the `asyncData()` [API hook](https://nuxtjs.org/api/) you don't have access to `this`, but there is a [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) model passed in that has the `params` object.